# Crystal Report how can I get data for every 5th of months

Tags: sql, vba, crystal-reports, data-analysis

How can I extract data for every 5th of the month?

For example, I want to have a report look like as following table in crystal report:

[image]

How can I make the column named [Total Jobs Created] a static value on report but run based on live database for the date after 5th of every next month?

For example, If let say today is 6th of Feb. After refresh the data, the [Total Jobs Created] value will be 123 static value.

I want the value of each month to be static value rather than dynamic value

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula such as IF Day({job_created_date}) < 6 Then 1 ELSE 0
SUM that formula by your Month group. 
Note: use SUM, not COUNT for this.

You could use a Running Total instead, but the conditional total approach has some advantages.